# Python setup script that survives a reboot

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, subprocess

As part of a PXE configuration, I'm trying to write a python script that survives a one time reboot to finish off some configuration.  Here's what I have so far:

I've created /etc/init.d/pxe_reboot:

```
#! /bin/sh
case "$1" in
   start)
      python /home/user/pxe_setup.py &
      ;;
   stop|restart|reload)
      ;;
esac
```

And I have the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os.path
import sys

def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=True)
    p.wait()
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

 def before_reboot():
      {stuff}

 def after_reboot():
      {more stuff}

 if os.path.isfile("/home/user/pxe_flag"):
      after_reboot()
      run_command("sudo rm /home/user/pxe_flag")
      run_command("sudo update-rc.d pxe_reboot remove")

 else:
      before_reboot()
      run_command("sudo touch /home/user/pxe_flag")
      run_command("sudo update-rc.d pxe_reboot defaults")
      run_command("sudo reboot")
```

This seems to mostly work, except that I notice some print statements I have in `after_reboot()` print out while the machine is shutting down, not on next boot.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve in python?

Comment: You do `sudo reboot` when shutting down ? An init script must not do this, it must just take care of the application state, nothing else.